# Which category of MFC application is best suited for my multiple window project

Tags: mfc

The application will have four windows and at a time it has to display one or two windows on a single monitor (5"x5") machine or dual monitor (5"x5") machine respectively. The application has two modes of operations; User Mode and Maintenance Mode. In user mode no user inputs through mouse or key board is required; however, application senses some inputs through some ways. Whereas, the other one is interactive in nature. In user mode application has to display either one window or two depending upon the no of displays available; if there is two displays available, it has to do its processing and display DIFFERENT sets of messages & small images on two displays. In maintenance mode either one or two windows have to be shown depending upon the no of displays available; if there is two displays available, it has to take some user inputs through keyboard or mouse and after doing little processing, it has to display SAME images and messages on two displays. Regarding processing requirement the application uses few TCP/IP sockets for message exchanges, communicates with few serial devices through serial ports and interacting with light weight database. The application won't have any menus; only on small displays it has to show some messages and small images; messages and images have to be updated very frequently.

My question is which category of MFC application (Dialog Based, SDI or MDI) is suitable for my application.

As of now the application is Dialog based application with one Modal Dialog and three Modeless dialogs. Depending upon the no of displays it creates either one Modal dialog & another modeless dialog (for single display) and at any moment it displays one dialog and keeps other dialog hidden and in case of dual displays it creates one Modal dialog and another three modeless dialog; however at a time it displays only two dialogs. PostMessage is being used for message exchange among the dialogs.

Any suggestion on this may help me a lot.

Comment: The solution you describe is very workable, is there a reason you're looking for an alternative?

Comment: First reason is I never used other two types; therefore I needed your opinions. Second, In maintenance mode of my application both screens have the same content yet, I'm exchanging same messages from one screen to another through PostMessage. Third, apart from some Static Text and images there is user id & password input text boxes which need to be shown on one screen and replicated at the same time on the other screen; otherwise, user may feel delay in accepting the key board inputs on one screen which is not activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In there anything you need that the present arrangement does not give you? It sounds like you have a good approach. MDI is a poor fit to multiple screens. SDI might be helpful if you need the modal dialog to scroll (It would replace your modal dialog with a CFormView).

Comment: I'm happy with the present arrangement except in one case where a textbox of one dialog accepts some inputs through key board and the same to be replicated to another textbox on second dialog.i.e.every time user presses a key,content of the textbox has to be replicated to the textbox on second dialog.When user comes into this mode textbox on one of the dialogs displayed on monitors are focused and displays the characters but to display the same on the other un-focused textbox on the other dialog takes some time to display the same.It would better if I could display same dialog on both screens.